# Expected value of normal CDF evaluated on another r.v.

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given $X$ and $Y$ two random variables. $X\sim N(0, 1)$.

My intuition is that $\mathbb E_Y[F_X(Y)] = F_X[\mathbb E_Y[Y]]$, where $F_X$ is the CDF of the normal distribution. Is this a known result? Under what conditions would this hold? What tools can I use to determine whether my intuition is correct?

Comment: We have $\mathbb E_Y[F_X(Y)] = P(X\leq Y)$ (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent) and $F_X[\mathbb E_Y[Y]] = P(X\leq \mathbb E_Y[Y])$. These are different quantities in general.